# How to check if a json value returned is null?

Tags: angular

I want to check if a json value is null. I want to be able to display a form to upload an image if `info.pic` is null otherwise display the image that is returned in the json.

My html

```
<div class="col-sm-9" *ngFor="let info of dInfo">
  <img [src]="'data:image/JPG;base64,' + info.pic"/>
</div>
      <h1>name: </h1>
      <p> {{ info.name }} </p>
    </div>

 // The upload form that I want to hide 
  <label for="image">Upload</label>
  <input #fileInput type="file" id="image"/>
  <button class="btn" (click)="upload()">Upload Image</button>
```

The service

```
byID(id: any): Observable<any>
 {
  return this.http.get('')
    .map(
      (response: Response) => {
        return response.json().info;
      }
    );
}
```

The component

```
getById(ID: any) {
  this.infoService.byID(ID)
    .subscribe(
      (dInfo2: DInterface[]) => {
        this.dInfo2 = dInfo2
      },
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

The interface

```
export interface DInterface {

   id: number;
   name: string;
   pic: any;
```

}

The JSON response

[http://imgur.com/a/u6KZu](https://imgur.com/a/u6KZu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*ngIf`.

In your case:

```
<img *ngIf="(info.pic | json) != '{}'" [src]="'data:image/JPG;base64,' + info.pic"/>
```

[Documentation for ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

**Update 1:**

Try with:

```
<img *ngIf="info?.pic" [src]="'data:image/JPG;base64,' + info.pic"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I use `=== {}` or `=== NULL`. Its returning a json object array like this here http://imgur.com/a/u6KZu you can see its returning pic as null

Comment: Couldn't this just be as simple as: `*ngIf="info.pic"`?

Comment: hmmm.. Have you tried just with `*ngIf="info.pic===null"`?

Comment: @katana314 Your solution worked. I can do `*ngIf="info.pic"` and `*nfIf="!info.pic"`

Comment: @ghan try putting `?.` operator, in case you still don't have the `info` object but your template is rendering.

Comment: @SrAxi Which version of TypeScript added that operator? I tried it in my current project and it gave a compile error.